# unknown error in sqlite in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, nsstring

I have made a function to get data from sqlite but somehow i am getting unknown error.I have used prepare statement concept here.Other functions like this are working fine but not this function.Please tell me what is the issue?

```
- (SubComponent*) getSeSubComponentDataBySubclientClientInspectionid:(NSString*)componentid : (NSString *)subclientid : (NSString *)clientId : (NSString *)inspectionid
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        const char *query_stmt = "select * FROM sesubcomponent WHERE subcomponentid = ? AND subclientid = ? AND clientid = ? AND inspectionid = ?";
        SubComponent *resultArray = [[SubComponent alloc]init];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            componentid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",componentid];
            subclientid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",subclientid];
            clientId=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",clientId];
            inspectionid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",inspectionid];

            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [componentid UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [subclientid UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [clientId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [inspectionid UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *component_id = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                          (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                resultArray.componentid = component_id;
                NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                  (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                resultArray.componentName = name;
                NSString *createddate = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                         (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                resultArray.componentcreateddate = createddate;
                NSString *subclientid = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                         (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
                resultArray.componentsubclientid = subclientid;
                NSString *clientid = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
                resultArray.componentClientid = clientid;
                NSString *entityid = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                      (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];
                resultArray.componentEntityid = entityid;
                NSString *inspectionid = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6)];
                resultArray.componentinspectionid = inspectionid;
                NSString *clientName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8)];
                resultArray.componentClientName = clientName;
                NSString *subclientName = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 9)];
                resultArray.componentSubclientName = subclientName;
                sqlite3_finalize(statement);  sqlite3_close(database);
                sqlite3_close(database);
                return resultArray;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"%s getSeSubComponentDataBySubclientClientInspectionid arrow is ",sqlite3_errmsg(database));

            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"getSeSubComponentDataBySubclientClientInspectionid error is %s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
          sqlite3_close(database);
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What is returning "unknown error"?

Comment: uknowen error is sqlite_errmsg()